# Why is Set-Content throwing this error?

Tags: powershell

I can recreate the issue with the below code sample

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\10.10.22.6\d$ -Credential $cred -Confirm:$false -Scope Global
Set-Content -Path 'Z:\__unc_test\Powershell\___datefile' -Value ([System.DateTime]::Now).ToString()

Get-ChildItem Z:\__unc_test
```

Get-ChildItem will return a listing of the directory so I know the New-PSDrive call is succeeding and the UNC is available via the Powershell.

However, the Set-Content call is failing with the following error:

```
Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path '\\10.10.22.6\d$\10.10.22.6\d$\10.10.22.6\d$\__unc_test\Powershell\___datefile'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Content -Path 'Z:\__unc_test\Powershell\___datefile' -Value ([System.DateTim ...
```

If you look at the error it appears Set-Content is attempting to resolve the path in some manner and is doing something very wacky.

Can anyone try and recreate this on their machine and/or explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?  Get-Item, Get-ChildItem, and Copy-Item all seem to work across that drive letter, but not Set-Content.

Comment: I was unable to recreate this. Quoting does not appear to change the outcome. The code as is worked for me. The path is repeated, in your example, which makes me think you did something that you are not showing here. Are you able to recreate this behaviour in a _new_ powershell session?

Comment: I noticed this behavior in a larger module and extracted the code out specifically to see if it was something I was doing.  Running this code in a fresh Powershell ISE tab will recreate the issue 100% of the time.  Literally the only other thing I'm doing is creating the credential object you see being used in the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can repro this issue on my machine. 
This only seems to happen if the file does not exist before you call Set-Content.
Easy solution, run this before you use set-content:

```
New-Item -Path 'Z:\__unc_test\Powershell\___datefile' -Type file -Force
```

This problem also does not occur if I use "net use" to add the drive.